# Cortana text queries

Tags: c#, windows, cortana

I am developing a Cortana App and I want to test my app using text queries (and also voice queries) but Cortana only activates my app when I use voice commands. Is it possible to test the app using only text?

What should I modify/program in the App to enable Cortana to call the App based on text queries?

I'm using a laptop with Windows 10.

Here is a sample of my VCD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
  <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="FruitsCommandSet_en-us">

    <AppName>Nutritional</AppName>
    <Example>Show nutritional information about fruits.</Example>

    <Command Name="GetFruitNames">
      <Example>Show the fruit nutritional facts.</Example>

      <ListenFor RequireAppName="ExplicitlySpecified">[Show] {builtin:AppName} details for [the] {FruitName}.</ListenFor>

      <Feedback>Loading fruit details...</Feedback>

      <Navigate />
    </Command>


    <PhraseTopic Label="FruitName">
    </PhraseTopic>

  </CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

Comment: Both text and voice activation should work the same way. When you constructed your VCD file, did you use the AppName tag for specifying your activation keyword? Or did you use the older legacy CommandName? Including some snippets of your VCD in your question should make it easier to work out what's going on.

Comment: I am using CommandPrefix tag for the activation word and ListenFor tags for the commands. I included a example.

Comment: Try using <AppName>. The problem is, you're using infix format (the builtin:AppName bit) but aren't specifying an AppName. The CommandPrefix is for legacy support of older winphone 8.x VCDs, which doesn't support the AppName tag. See [this sample VCD](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand/shared/AdventureWorksCommands.xml) for an example, and see how you go.

Comment: Thanks but .. there must be something still wrong because I still can only activate the app using voice.

Comment: Odd. Can you try adding a ListenFor that puts your app name at the start? And can you try the adventureworks sample and see if you're getting the same problem with that?

Comment: Yeah... I'll try with advetureworks now because it did not worked even for one word sentences + {before, after, beforeOrAfter}.

Comment: Uhm.. AdventureWorks is for WinPhone .. I don't have one here and the emulator is not working right now. Any example that works in Win 10? BTW this is my real VCD http://pastebin.com/p6C86rck

Comment: The adventureworks sample definitely works on PC. Visual studio defaults to ARM as that's the first build configuration in the project files, but it will work fine if you switch it to x86 or x64.

Comment: It says I'm using a version of Windows Universal Runtime that is too old (10.0.10240.16430). I use Win 10 Enterprise and I checked to update the OS but there isn't any update available..

Comment: It sounds like your business hasn't distributed the November win10 update yet (1511), or you haven't installed vs2015 update 1 and gotten the new SDK yet. You should be able to edit the project files to go back to 10240 though, there weren't any API changes that I recall.

Comment: I found what was the problem. It was a dot "." at the end of the sentences and may be some other semantic error. But the dot is fundamental! If I include the dot at the end of the ListenFor text Cortana will not be able to recognize the query even if I add the dot at the end of the query.

Comment: Ah, sorry. stack overflow formatted that so that the period was off the screen, so I missed that in your sample. You definitely want to avoid having extra punctuation in your ListenFor statements. Is it working okay for voice and text input now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting here so the final answer is more clear from the discussion above.

The VCD file John was using had features that require the AppName to be set (The builtin:AppName marker), and had some punctuation marks in the ListenFor statement that made text matching more difficult.

It's a good idea to avoid having punctuation within a ListenFor statement (such as periods). While speech recognition works on a confidence-based matching approach and will cope, text input is a bit more stringent.